# Visual studio csc compilation fails intermittently

Tags: visual-studio-2012, csc

Whenever I compile any project on visual studio it fails with the following errors:

> 2>CSC : error CS1583:
> '$path\obj\Debug\CSC1DCAF528D2BE4F9F8084DAE56ECCD9AD.TMP' is not a
> valid Win32 resource file

There are a number of projects in my solution and the project for which I get this error changes randomly.

I have to compile and interrupt several times before I am able to complete the compilation. When I interrupt the build process I get the following error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) failed to
> start. If this problem persists, please repair your Visual Studio
> installation via 'Add or Remove Programs' in Control Panel.
> --------------------------- OK
> --------------------------- 4
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
>
> error MSB4018: The "Csc" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
>
> error MSB4018: System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
>
> error MSB4018:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.303\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
>
> error MSB4018:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_HasExited()
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
>
> error MSB4018:    at  Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.TerminateToolProcess(Process proc, Boolean isBeingCancelled)
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.HandleToolNotifications(Process
> proc)
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool,
> String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
> error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>
> 4>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

I am getting the same error with other versions of visual studio. So it looks like an issue with csc.exe.
I have tried all the fixes that I could find on google, including re-installation, repair and uninstallation of .net frameworkds, visual studio. The only option that is left with me is to format my computer and build my dev environment from scratch.

Any help in resolving this will would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that you have access rights to all the folders csc is trying to write to? Or that you have enough disk space? (No idea if these could be the cause, but just trying to work out what could cause csc to fail.)

Comment: Yes.. and I launch visual studio as an administrator.

Comment: You'll have to get your machine healthy again.  That invariably starts by disabling anti-malware first, checking the health of the disk drive next.  If you use free crapware like Avast, AVG, ESET then get rid of it completely.

Comment: did you find any resolution to your question? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had to reinstall visual studio to fix this. I am not sure but I believe my machine was subsequently formatted a couple of times after this. It wasn't due to visual studio but I am not facing this issue anymore

Comment: found the answer, I am using VS 2015 and change the processor that build is configured from Mixed CPU to x85. And it works now! Let me know if you want me to post this as answer. Cheers